# sorting threads in mutt

Tags: mutt

I'd like to have mutt sort messages newest first, and have threads displayed with the newest message at the top of the thread.  Right now I have the message list in the correct order, but the sub-sorting within threads is backwards (newest at bottom of thread).  Here's my current configuration...

```
set sort = threads
set sort_aux = reverse-last-date-received
```

Is there any option to control sorting within threads?

Answer (score 10):

If I understand you correctly, you're reversed the sorting of threads but you meant to reverse the sorting within threads, so swap them:

```
set sort=reverse-threads
set sort_aux=date-received
```

I think Mutt always displays the thread title on the oldest message in the thread, even when it ends up sorted at the bottom.